# Android ContentProvider NOSQL Database

Tags: android, nosql, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to develop a custom contentprovider, that uses a NOSQL DB to store data, because the static columnmodel of sqlite doesn't fit to my needs.

I have found out that CouchDB provides a mobile version for Android called TouchDB, I also found an [example](https://github.com/deepwinter/rhus-android)  using it for its contentprovider, but I don't really get whats going on in there...

So I would like to ask if someone could provide me with some help who to implement a NOSQL-DB (TouchDB or anything else) properly to work together with a contentprovider.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you bothering with a `ContentProvider` in the first place?

Comment: I changed my solution i don't need the TouchDB anymore but thanks for the interest.